# Is there a good podcast about concurrency?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, multicore, parallel-processing

Concurrency is one of the hot topics on quite a few technology podcasts. Yet I couldn't find a podcast dedicated to concurrency programming fundamentals, techniques etc. If there's no podcast that specializes on concurrency which of technology podcasts highlights this topic best?

Answer (score 6):

Also not aware of specific podcasts dedicated to this.

But: I found the following two podcasts fairly interesting in regard to concurrency and scalability.

https://www.se-radio.net/2008/03/episode-89-joe-armstrong-on-erlang/

https://www.se-radio.net/2008/09/episode-109-ebays-architecture-principles-with-randy-shoup/

Answer (score 3):

Others have already mentioned it, but I thought I'd emphasize that SE Radio have [quite a few good concurrency episodes](http://www.se-radio.net/tags/concurrency), including a 3-part primer on concurrency. I would recommend SE Radio in general as a great resource.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a podcast that is dedicated to concurrency, but you can find interesting discussions about concurrency in:

- [Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/tags/Concurrency/) (mostly video but I listen to the audio track in the car)
- [Intel](http://software.intel.com/en-us/videos/category/multi-core/1/1/)
- [Software engineering radio](http://www.se-radio.net/tags/concurrency)

The links are to the concurrency tag.

Answer (score 1):

For parallel scientific applications, see [RCE](http://rce-cast.com).

Answer (score 0):

I follow [High Scalability](http://highscalability.com/) RSS feeds.
It's actually about web stuff, but you might find it interesting.